# Kotlin multiplatform: GC does not release memory - how to force it to release?

Tags: ios, kotlin-multiplatform

I’m developing a network extension on iOS and I want to use KMM to share some code between Android and iOS.

iOS is quite strict on RAM usage and it only provides 50 MB for network extensions. KMM does not release memory often/soon enough and iOS kills my app.

The problem seems to be the same as in this issue on github: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/3595

I’ve tried calling GC.collect() but it does not seem to be available anymore.

Any solutions? Can I use KMM in low RAM environments?

Example:

```
  @Throws(Exception::class)
  fun decodeJson(json: String) {
      val decodedJson = Json{ ignoreUnknownKeys = true }.decodeFromString<JsonObj>(json)
  }
```

Even though decodedJson is not referenced anywhere, KMM does not release the memory.

Comment: What version of Kotlin and libraries are you using? Also the example you provided looks incorrect (you're decoding a string into `Json`, which is the mapper?) To help avoiding reflection you could pass the serilaizer manually into `decodeFromString()`

Comment: kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 

I've fixed the example. Also, it is not related to Json. If I create a big object that has a lot of data (Strings for example) and delete all references to it, KMM would not release the memory as well. It seems that KMM GC thinks that 50mb RAM usage is nothing to worry about.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kotlin/Native development, but I suspect that your issue is due to the new memory model, enabled by default in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew17.html#performance-improvements-for-the-new-memory-manager. The linked ticket there leads to this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-53182/New-memory-manager-Unexpected-memory-usage-on-IOS. Does the workaround in the comment ("try adding `"-Xallocator=std"` to `freeCompilerArgs`") help?

Comment: if I add the flag, it does release the memory after 5 secs or so, which is better for sure.